Remove new lines in between strings from a text file
Basically I have a text file with IDs and different dates, I managed to remove all the lines that I do not need by targeting the date.
Sample text file:
ID Date
asdf232e 08/08/2024
asdf232f 08/07/2024
asdf232g 08/12/2024
asdf232h 08/08/2024
asdf232j 08/10/2024

The snippet below matches the whole line which date is not 08/08 and replaces everything for ""
Get-Content textfile.txt | % {$_ -replace "^(?!.*08/08.*)",""} | Set-Content textfileCleansed.txt
And so I get this output:
ID Date
asdf232e 08/08/2024


asdf232h 08/08/2024


What I basically want is to remove all the new lines to get something like:
ID Date
asdf232e 08/08/2024
asdf232h 08/08/2024

As later on in the process, I do a Compare-Object between files and PowerShell fetches all those new lines included in both files.
Here's what I've tried so far:
I've tried to trim the whole content, but it only trims the beginning and ending new lines in the text file.
I also tried to Get-Content textfile.txt | % {$_ -replace "'n",""} and Get-Content textfile.txt | % {$_ -replace "\x08",""}


It's simpler to use Where-Object for filtering:
# ... | Set-Content textfileCleansed.txt omitted for brevity.
(Get-Content textfile.txt -First 1), 
(Get-Content textfile.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '08/08' }) 


Short answer: use Where-Object not ForEach-Object
Longer answer: depending on a few things there are a few different ways to go.
I personally think using the *-Csv cmdlets is the best way.
Import-Csv -Path $InputFilePath -Delimiter ' ' | 
    Where-Object -Property Date -Match '08/08' | 
    Export-Csv -Path $OutputFilePath -UseQuotes Never -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ' '

It would be the most elastic method, especially because it makes much easier to manipulate the data, should that ever become necessary.

Indeed, object-based processing is the most robust - if slow - approach (which in the case at hand is only an option if none of the fields contain spaces themselves, i.e. if the input file is truly a structured text file designed for programmatic processing).
Worth nothing that the -UseQuotes parameter is supported only in PowerShell (Core) 7, and that  -NoTypeInformation is unnecessary  there, as it is invariably implied.

I fixed it! It's a lot of work around and I'll be trying to simplify it but here's my fix:
First off remove undesired rows:
Get-Content textfile.txt | % {$_ -replace "^(?!.*08/08.*)",""} | Set-Content textfileCleansed.txt

Then, remove the newlines by joining the whole remaining strings into one single line:
(Get-Content textfileCleansed) -join '' | Set-Content textfileJoined

Finally I do replace the end of each string with a new line
Get-Content textfile.txt | % {$_ -replace "/2024","`n"} |% {$_.trim()| Set-Content textfileExpected.txt


-replace "^(?!.*08/08.*)", "" doesn't replace anything, because your regex - due to only containing a negative lookahead assertion ((?!...)) - doesn't capture anything - see  https://regex101.com/r/fWHuix/1. Therefore, Get-Content textfile.txt | % {$_ -replace "^(?!.*08/08.*)",""} is therefore a no-op: all input lines are passed through. Even if you did get this to work, it would amount to a needlessly complicated approach.
